# How to automatically get {a,b,c} from {x -> a, y -> b, z -> c}?

Tags: equation-solving, graphics3d, list-manipulation

I want to get the graphic of a 3D-straight line:

First:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
FindInstance[1/4 (-1 + x) == -y == 1/3 (-2 - z), {x, y, z}, Reals, 2]

(*{{x -> 1/2, y -> 1/8, z -> -(13/8)}, {x -> 3/5, y -> 1/10, 
  z -> -(17/10)}}*)
```

Then the " x->  y->  z->" need to be deleted manually and get two point {1/2, 1/8, -(13/8)}, {3/5, 1/10, -(17/10)}.

Finally:

```
Graphics3D[InfiniteLine[{{1/2, 1/8, -(13/8)}, {3/5, 1/10, -(17/10)}}],
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

How to combine these two pieces of code into one piece? Or, How to automatically get {a,b,c} from {x -> a, y -> b, z -> c}?

Comment: You are looking for [`Values`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html).

Comment: @MarcoB great. This is a 3rd way to do it. May be you can make this an answer also. We now only need 7 more ways to get to 10 :)

Comment: OK. Thank you. :-) @MarcoB

Comment: @Nasser an update: only three to reach your claimed number of alternatives

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do this. (in Mathematica, the rule of thumb is that there are at least 10 ways to do the same thing :)

But one way could be

```
Clear["Global`*"];
sol = FindInstance[1/4 (-1 + x) == -y == 1/3 (-2 - z), {x, y, z},  Reals, 2];
pts = sol /. Rule[x_, y_] :> y;
Graphics3D[InfiniteLine[pts], 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you. :-) @Nasser

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get `{a,b,c}` from `{x -> a, y -> b, z -> c}` you should use [`Values`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html):

```
In[10]:= Values[{x -> a, y -> b, z -> c}]

Out[10]= {a, b, c}
```

For what it's worth I only read the post title, so there may be some context I'm missing here.

Answer (score 4):

```
sol = FindInstance[1/4 (-1 + x) == -y == 1/3 (-2 - z), {x, y, z}, 
  Reals, 2];
{x,y,z}/.sol
sol[[;; , ;; , 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you. :-) @cvgmt

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be

```
sol = FindInstance[1/4 (-1 + x) == -y == 1/3 (-2 - z), {x, y, z}, 
  Reals, 2]

sol /. Rule[a_, b_] :> b
```

Answer (score 2):

I am still a bit jealous of the amazing performance given by @cvgmt the other day, so the following also works:

```
sol = FindInstance[1/4 (-1 + x) == -y == 1/3 (-2 - z), {x, y, z}, 
  Reals, 2]

Apply[#2 &, sol, {2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible way to do it:

```
{Last @@@ sol[[1]], Last @@@ sol[[2]]}
```

Answer (score 2):

One more

```
FoldList[#1 /. #2 &, {x, y, z}, sol][[2 ;; 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a surprise that you can use `Fold` as well in the following manner

```
Table[Fold[#1 /. #2 &, {x, y, z}, sol[[i]]], {i, 1, 2}]
```